# Ошибка с переменными

Tags: python, ос

Хочу через python os оптимизировать рутинную задачу

Есть код:

```
passTerminal = input("Введи пароль")
os.system("sudo apt update", passTerminal)
```

На второй строчке выводится ошибка:

```
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: f"sudo apt update {passTerminal}"

Comment: Правильно пишет

Comment: Потому что функция принимает один параметр и это строка со всеми командами

Answer (score 0):

```py
sudo_password = input("Введи пароль: ")
command = 'sudo -S ls'.split()
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
p.communicate(sudo_password + '\n')
```